# Как сохранять значение переменной и добавлять единицу по событию?

Tags: html, ajax, прокрутка

Данные отдаются карточками по 20 штук, таких страниц может быть разное количество от 1 до бесконечности.

Задача: подгрузка ajax при скролле.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    ajaxLoadScroll ();

});

function ajaxLoadScroll(){
    var countListing = 1; //так как первая страница уже выведена при подгрузке необходимо получать начиная со второй

   $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        var $container = $('.container').height() - 500; 
        if($(this).scrollTop() > $container) {

           $(document).off('scroll');
           countListing++;

         $.getJSON('/subscriptions/' + countListing, function(data) {
                  var cards = data.cards; 
                 if (cards.length !== 0) {
                 } else {
                 }
         });
     });
});
}
```

Явная проблема в том, что вторую страницу получает, а последующие нет (по очевидным причинам). Как хранить состояние переменной и запускать скрипт подгрузки заново до тех пор пока cards не станет пустым массивом?

Comment: если `cards.length !== 0` можно просто заново навешивать обработчик на скролл

Comment: @Grundy то есть переменную с высотой контейнера обновлять при каждой подгрузке, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: не понял про что ты